# jquery click select and enable/disable input button

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have several forms with select/input buttons on one page.  I want to click on a select form, get the id of it, and toggle disable on a button with the same name except its a class not an id.

my code so far:

```
$("#main").on("click",".list", function () {
        var j = $(this).attr("id");
        if(j) {alert(j);}
        $("."+j).attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
```

I cannot seem to reference anything with `"."+j` any ideas?

```
<h2>Towns / Suburbs</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="">

        <select class="list" name="data_change" id="towns" size=10>
            <option>foo</option><option>bar</option>
        </select>

        <div class="buttonGroup">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="Delete" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="Add" value="Add">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="Edit" value="Edit" class="towns">
</div>
        </form>
```

Comment: it alerts fine, I get 'towns', but then with '.'+j i get nothing.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two class attribues,
If you have more than one class, separate them with space.

```
<input type="submit" class="button towns" name="Edit" value="Edit" />
```